# Api data null whe nthe pages load even i use initState

Tags: flutter, dart, http

im using post method to get api data/response.body in initState and i get all the response/data then i put it in my variables `surveyData`, but when i load the pages with widget looped by the response.body length it goes error and say response.body.length is null but when i save the text editor/ hot reload, all the data entered and it's not null anymore and the widget appear.

fyi: the `http`.post method is my own function not from `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` so don't mind it

> Variables that contain the response

```
  dynamic surveyData;
```

> initState Code

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        // GET PAGES
        surveyPages = widget.surveyPages;
    
        // GET FORM DETAIL
        http.post(
          'survey-pre-mitsu/form-detail',
          body: {
            "survey_form_header_id": 1,
          },
        ).then(
          (res) {
            surveyData = res['data'];
          },
        );
      }
```

> Widget that looped by surveyData.length

```
  for (var i = 0; i < surveyData.length; i++)
                AdditionalForm(questionLabel: surveyData[i]['label'],
                  questionType: surveyData[i]['type'],),
```

> This is what the error

[image]

> And this is what it looks like when i do hot reload

[image]

Comment: Obviously the **surveyData** is null, since you're calling **length** on it and blowing up. Can you print out **res** to check what it brings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest you to use future builder to resolve this problem.

Comment: the builder must return something and the problem is in the looping data.length, the looping cannot be return

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest performing **post**(even though its your own code) as a **asynchronous** operation,  hence not inside **initState()**. Preferably write the logic in a separate class/file with packages like a provider package. Try this first and then post the error after that.

Comment: im working on company project so i can only continue the code before

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Some delay , In this Delay you can show a loading icon . for delay you can use :

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {

// Here you can write your code

  setState(() {
    // Here you can write your code for open new view
  });

});
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: where should i put this delayed function ? in my widget that i want to show ?

Comment: in your initstate